# How to build multi row formula using Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to build a new column that has the running total of a specific column. Are there directives available to do this? Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Multi-row directives are not available in CDF(Wrangler) for this particular scenario. Running total of a specific column can be achieved through window aggregation plugin,
https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/760381517/Window+Aggregation+Analytics+Spark

Eg.
new_col:Accumulate(specific_col, 1, false) as aggregate function.

Make sure you define the right partition column if you need rolling sum for a group for rows, if not create a dummy col for considering whole table as one partition. Also make sure table is not huge in the latter case.